# Python & Cython code analysis and call graphs

Tags: python, code-analysis, cython

I am looking for a tool that can analyze Cython and Python code. I am particularly interested in call graphs.

A bit of background: I am refactoring a package that has some rather "organically grown" modules. I suspect I can prune away quite a few methods in those modules. For that purpose, I'd need to know which other parts of the package depend on pruning candidates. Furthermore, I hope to get some information on possible "feature envy" of my classes.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have good test coverage of your code or another way of easily exercising all its functionality? Accurate static analysis of a language as dynamic as Python would be hard -- you may be better off using profiler output.

Comment: I have "smoke tests" at best (in the sense of testing some very basic functionality and checking whether it blows up). Unfortunately, I do not test on the unit level.

Most of the code is Cython actually (and thus not really dynamic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a dependency tree with [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/), but it will be only in python space.

You can get a call hierarchy for some calls by profiling your "smoke tests". See [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html) how to enable profiling for cython.

Comment: I didn't know about snakefook so far. Thanks!